# Hola, al parecer está bien y detecta los movimientos, pero cuando dejo de moverme la pantalla se congela, sólo cuando me muevo fluye, por qué sucede?

Tags: python, funciones, tkinter, opencv, inteligencia-artificial

**El programa funciona, pero la pantalla se queda congelada**

```
     
     def show_frame():
         _, frame = cap.read()
         frame = deteccion(frame)
         cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)


----------
```

**Aquí hago una funcion para detectar el movimento**

````
```def deteccion(frame):
     while True:
        _, frame = cap.read()
        _, frame2 = cap.read()
````

Hago la diferenciacion

```
        diff = cv2.absdiff(frame,frame2)
```

Lo convierto en gris

```
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY)
        blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
        _, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=3)
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(dilated, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

creo el bucle para que recorra los contornos

````
        for cnt in contours:
            if cv2.contourArea(cnt) < 50000:
               continue
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            return frame```
````